# Encrypt/Decrypt password

Tags: php, zend-framework, encryption, passwords

Well it is an old question but always is it redirected to hashing. Because it is a "bad" practice to be able to reverse engineer a password.

Well I want to be able to reverse the password but be able to store the passwords safely.

Why do I want to reverse it? simple, we have all kind of systems to keep track on post its is a waste of time. Current all the password are saved plain in a document.

We/I want a system so we can "look" the system up and get the password. To get to the passwords you need to be logged in, so that will be the first layer of defence against hacking.

But are there any other things I could do to prevent easy access to the passwords.

I was looking into [zf2 MCrypt](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Crypt/Symmetric/Mcrypt.php) to encrypt/decrypt the passwords.

Any better encrypt/decrypt tools?

Comment: This question is way too broad; you should ask a security expert about such things. There are a million pitfalls you should worry about, but there's no sense in explaining them all here.

Comment: Noted, changed my question if there are better encrypt/decrypt tools

Comment: you can try arc4 stream cipher, then XOR it. Just keep the key. But I'd suggest to sticking to hashing, maybe with bcrypt. You should also worry about getting sued by your users for storing passwords in insecure ways.

Comment: Thank, I use zf2/BCypt indead for passwords that shouldn't be "readable". About the law etc, did not think about that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well I want to be able to reverse the password but be able to store the passwords safely.

Those two statements are mutually-exclusive.  If the password can be determined, it's not safe.  This is fixed by *hashing* the password instead of 2-way encrypting it.

> To get to the passwords you need to be logged in, so that will be the first layer of defence against hacking.

No it isn't.  It's an illusion of security.  If the passwords are compromised, then the requirement of "being logged in" won't really be difficult for an attacker to achieve, would it?

> But are there any other things I could do to prevent easy access to the passwords.
>   ...
>   Any pitfalls I should worry about?

Yes, absolutely.  The pitfall is that the passwords are readable, and that should never happen.  The only way to be certain that passwords can't be read is to not keep them in a readable format.

1. Hash the password, store the hash and the salt.
2. When a user enters a password, hash the entered password and compare it to the hash.

There is no legitimate reason to store passwords insecurely, and doing so is genuinely irresponsible to your users.  There's a *very high* probability that users re-use the same passwords for multiple services.  By getting passwords from your system an attacker could very easily gain access to your users' banking services and other highly-sensitive things.

Never store recoverable passwords.  Ever.  End of story.

Comment: `No it isn't. It's an illusion of security. If the passwords are compromised, then the requirement of "being logged in" won't really be difficult for an attacker to achieve, would it?` is true that is why I said it is the first layer, just like a FireWall needs multiple layers. Then I have an other question how do you remember all the password to gain access to other systems. Writing them on post it's isn't a good idea either. Like I stated I know it is bad practice but I am trying to find a good way but you are just confirming it is bad..

Comment: @Hendriq: `"Writing them on post it's isn't a good idea either"` The key difference here is whether the users expose their passwords themselves or whether *you* expose their passwords for them without telling them. - `"I know it is bad practice but I am trying to find a good way"` Again, mutually exclusive statements. It sounds like you've decided on a course of action and are trying to justify it. That course of action is widely known to be bad practice.  There is no justification. You're free to engage in irresponsible practices, but that doesn't change the fact that it's irresponsible.

Comment: No I am trying to find a way so I can manage the passwords with my collegas without having a lot of paperwork every where. It could be in an app. Or perhaps some keychain but I have no clue what the best action is, that is why this question. So not for justifying (although I see your point in it). But more in how other people manage a lot of passwords.